# Over stayer in South Africa?

Tags: visas, overstaying, south-africa, denial-of-entry

I overstayed by one day in South Africa two years ago. I am going back there on holiday this October 2019 using my New Zealand passport,and of course getting a visa in NZ before going.
Can I be blocked at O Tambo airport when I arrive, or will the undesirable status have been lifted by this time?
I submitted an appeal against this two years ago...but never received any response from SA. I have sent many e- mails, and phoned numerous times for help.....nothing!

The consulate in Wellington can't help,neither the visa company in Auckland.

How can I check if my NZ passport still has a block on it for SA ? I don't wasn't to be turned back on my arrival in SA.

Comment: If you're granted the visa you're applying for I think you can fairly assume your ban has expired. However, border guards everywhere have wide discretion to deny access for all sorts of reasons and having a visa doesn't guarantee entry.

Comment: Thanks, sounds reassuring, but still waiting for someone who has experienced this, and what happened to them on arrival in S A.

Comment: how did you get on getting into SA? Having the same issue…

Answer (score 3):

I have dealt with many individuals who have overstayed. Most recently a Thai national  who  travelled to RSA after changing his passport name (Fraudulently). Immigration picked this up and sent him back.
My suggestion is that you make inquiries to VFS Global who operate in both our countries.
In New Zealand they have offices in Auckland and Wellington.
Website https://www.vfsglobal.com/en/individuals/index.html.

I can also make inquiries on your behalf when I visit VFS in two days time.

Note: Our home affairs is terrible at responding to emails. I have personnel experience on dealing with them. This is also evident from numerous similar comments in this forum.!