# What if my flight is delayed/cancelled leaving South Africa on my 90th day?

Tags: air-travel, overstaying, south-africa

Planning a trip to South Africa but leaving on day 90.  I know that I don't need a visa when traveling 90 days or less, but what would happen if my flight is delayed or cancelled on that 90th day?

Comment: Bad things.  It's best to leave a bit of a buffer by leaving on the 89th day, or even the 88th.

Comment: You end up like this guy with an "undesirable" status: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/134658/over-stayer-in-south-africa. It's almost never a good idea to push your visit to the absolute maximum number of days allowed.

Comment: The closing of this thread should not occur as this is common issue with travelers who leaves on the last day of their valid stay in any county. If a flight have been cancelled or postponed, one can take the next flight out. The Airport Authorities will issue a memo stating the cancelled flight whilst the Airline should issue similar notice for immigration purpose. There will be no case of "overstay". Must be next available flight out. The airline have to provide accommodation, meals and transportation (if any) at their airline costs.